# Eventos do jQuery Vs. arrow functions?

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6

Ao executar o seguinte código:

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
   console.log("Meu valor é: " + $(this).val());   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="1">Clique-me</button>
```

O valor do botão é retornado normalmente. Mas em:

```js
$("button").on("click", ()=>{
   console.log("Meu valor é " +$(this).val());   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="1">Clique-me</button>
```

Usando *arrow function* no evento acusa o erro no jQuery:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Vejam que estou a usar a última versão `3.3.1` do jQuery.

Alguém saberia dizer por quê a *arrow function* não funciona em casos de eventos do jQuery visto que o ES6 não é algo tão novo assim (também chamado de ECMAScript 2015) lançado em [junho de 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) (quase 3 anos!)?

Comment: Diretamente não há como. Mas pode fazer uso do `event.currentTarget` que é o alvo do evento. Veja esta pergunta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670401/using-jquery-this-with-es6-arrow-functions-lexical-this-binding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *arrow function* funciona com o jQuery, o que não funciona é o `$(this)`. Isso não é implementando pelo jQuery porque [não é possível](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3620#issuecomment-294132658).

> Arrow functions don't have their own `this` binding so it's technically
>   impossible to use the `this` binding jQuery provides with an arrow
>   function.

Tradução livre:

> *Arrow functions* não são propriamente vinculadas ao `this`, então é tecnicamente impossível usar a vinculação ao `this` fornecida pelo
>   jQuery em uma *arrow function*.

[Isso é descrito na especificação do ECMAScript2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> An *ArrowFunction* does not define local bindings for **arguments**,
>   **super**, **this**, or **new.target**. Any reference to **arguments**, **super**, **this**, or **new.target** within an *ArrowFunction* must resolve to a binding in a lexically enclosing
>   environment. Typically this will be the Function Environment of an
>   immediately enclosing function.

Tradução livre:

> Uma *Arrow function* não define um vínculo local para **arguments**,
>   **super**, **this** ou **new.target**. Qualquer referência a **arguments**, **super**, **this** ou **new.target** em uma *Arrow
>   function* deve ser vinculado ao escopo léxico ao qual ela pertence.
>   Tipicamente, o escopo adotado será o da função imediatamente acima.

Para contornar o problema, você pode pegar o objeto de origem do evento através do parâmetro da função, assim poderá acessar seus atributos:

```js
$("button").on("click", event =>{
    console.log("Meu valor é " +event.target.getAttribute('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="1">Clique-me</button>
```

Comment: Poderia traduzir o texto (adaptar com sua palavras seria o ideal)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Feito! Foi um pouco difícil definir quais palavras deveriam ter sido traduzidas e quais não, já que muitas delas são "jargões universais" da área. Caso eu tenha traduzido alguma palavra que não deveria, ou deixado de traduzir, avisem-me que que efetuarei a correção. Ou até mesmo edite a pergunta e aplique-a. Caso haja um erro, façam o mesmo.